# Berg blick or Blick berg?

Tags: english-to-german

I am hoping someone can advise as to the correct word order for the translation of "mountain view". A friend that was fluent in German says berg blick. I also came across a German Shepherd Dog breeder that has used blick berg or blickberg as a kennel name. Any knowledgeable input would be appreciated.

Comment: What did your dictionary say?

Answer (score 11):

»Bergblick« is the correct translation of »Mountain View«. »Bergblick« is mentally expanded to »Blick auf den Berg / zum Berg«, whereas »Blickberg« would probably be interpreted as a proper name, like »Blick mountain« in English.

(There's also a real mountain surnamed »Blocksberg« and related to witchcraft (check [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Blocksberg)), maybe that's what the kennel was named.)

Answer (score 3):

It is “Bergblick” as one can see from numerous hotel and restaurant names.

Answer (score 2):

> "mountain view"

The base here is *view*, determined by the word order. It's pretty the same in German.

So one takes `Blick` which further will be described more specific.

> Was für ein Blick genießt du? - 
>   *What kind of view you enjoy?*
>   Einen Bergblick - *A mountain view*

Answer (score 1):

To me as a native speaker "Bergblick" sounds awkward. dict.cc suggest "Bergansicht" which is even stranger. I wouldn't express it in one word but rather use "Sicht auf die Berge" ("view onto the mountains"). None of the suggestions beside that are wrong, they just sound weird to us. :)